# On javascript click return variable to QTWebkit or PyQT

Tags: javascript, d3.js, pyqt4

Say you have a block of javascript code using the D3 library as follows:

```
node.append("image")
.on("click", function(d) {
    // Get variable d in PyQT or QTWebKit
})
```

How do I get the variable *d* when the node is clicked? I'm looking at getting this done in PyQT4.

Comment: What is the type of the variable? There are quite strict limitations on what can be passed directly between javascript and Qt. Look at [`evaluateJavaScript`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#evaluateJavaScript) and [`addToJavaScriptWindowObject`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qwebframe.html#addToJavaScriptWindowObject).

Comment: @ekhumoro It should be just a text variable. For *evaluateJavaScript* and *addToJavaScriptWindowObject*, is the control from within Qt or from JS?

Comment: Text is fine. The first evaluates javascript code from within Qt; the second gives access to Qt methods and properties from within javascript. Just read the linked docs if you want to know more.

Comment: @ekhumoro: I gave it a try and used this example: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447011/pyqt-pyside-webkit-and-exposing-methods-from-to-javascript), but not much progress. I am unable to see the object passed in from PyQT, it seems to be null when I do something like this in javascript: `alert(document.getElementById('printer'))` Can you provide an example of how to get the object in javascript?

Comment: Well, that is a DOM method, which has no relevance to the example you linked to. I don't know how it could be made any clearer. You just reference the object like any other javascript variable: i.e. `printer` or `window.printer`.

Comment: @ekhumoro Yeah, the only reason for trying the DOM method was because everything I tried gave me "undefined". printer, window.printer does not work as well. I am clueless as to how to do it besides overloading the alert function to do what I need.

Comment: Are you saying that the example you linked to somehow doesn't work for you? I just tested it myself to make doubly sure, and it all works fine for me. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: @ekhumoro The example works for me if I run it as is. In my case, there are a few issues that I can think of that may cause problems. Firstly, I'm dealing with Javascript within the D3 library. Secondly, I am using PySide and not PyQt. I am able to get Python to reference functions within Javascript, but not the other way round.

Comment: There is no reason why using PySide should make any difference, but I suppose D3 might. You're going to have to provide a small, self-contained example that demonstrates the problem if you want more help, though.